# Hide toolbar in expo app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

How do I hide the toolbar in an expo react native application.? Though I have added it in the Header tag. I have attached the code as well as the screenshot.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Item, Input, Icon, Button, Text } from 'native-base';

export default class ScreenScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Search',

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
    <Header searchBar rounded>
      <Item>
        <Icon name="ios-search" />
        <Input placeholder="Search anything.." />
        <Icon name="ios-people" />
      </Item>
      <Button transparent>
        <Text>Search</Text>
      </Button>
    </Header>
  </Container>
);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

[This is a screenshot of what I am presently get from this code. I want a way to remove the top toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkzNN.png)

[Expected toolbar after adding search bar tag in the header tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgxtz.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, recommend reading documentation of the libraries you use.

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,

  };
```