# Removing Search Bar

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, searchbar

I've been working with React-Native and Expo lately. I need a button to open a website in the browser but the search bar (top) and the icon bar should not appear either. Here is a picture to make everything a bit more understandable:

[image]

**Heres the Code i used:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    result: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button title="Open WebBrowser" onPress={this._handlePressButtonAsync} />
        <Text>{this.state.result && JSON.stringify(this.state.result)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://expo.io');
    this.setState({ result });
  };
}
```

Comment: Your English is fine, but you could have either looked at the `expo` documentation or searched here (Stack Overflow): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155181/hide-toolbar-in-expo-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide toolbar in expo app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155181/hide-toolbar-in-expo-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking to remove the url-bar on top and bottom navigation from *SFSafariViewController*, then it is **not possible**. The native safari-view-controller is supposed to let the user know that they are on a web-browser with the familiar safari UI.

If you really want to just show a webpage with no controlls, just use [react-native-webview](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webview/). You can render this on any react-native view and will not have the navigation bar or the top search bar.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#specifying-navigationoptions-for-a-screen), you can hide it like so:

```
 static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };
```